# Asynchronous WCF service calls from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, asynchronous-wcf-call

I have written a windows service that utilises asynchronous WCF service calls.
Upon testing, it seems that the method on the service executes perfectly but the callback to my windows service itself isn't being handled.

Upon reading the logging, I came across the following entry where my asynchronous service call should have returned:

```
The description for Event ID 0 from source gupdate cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
```

Could this be related to the account the service is running under or could there be another reason why this is happening? This one is under NetworkService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**gupdate** is the program used by Google to update their locally installed applications. So this entry has nothing to do with your problems.

Please try to run the service temporarily under your own administrator login credentials to see if this fixes the issue.